# How to remove repetition from hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap

I am trying to add the instruction from json field to the listview, but it is giving me repetition of data. How can i remove this repetition and add value only single time. Below is the snippet i am trying. I don't khow where i'm going wrong.

```
for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    instruction = Html.fromHtml((String) point
                            .get("html_instructions"));
                    str = instruction.toString();


                    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String[] values = map1.values().toArray(new String[map1.size()]);
                    if(values.length <= 0)
                    {
                        map1.put("instruction", str);
                    }
                    else{

                    for ( a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {

                        if ((values[a].contains(str))) 
                        {

                            break;
                        }
                        if(a>=values.length)
                        {
                            map1.put("instruction", str);
                        }
                      }

                }
```

i am drawing the path between two geolocation,,,so retrieving the points from json and adding the the list.and also getting instructions from json and addinh them in hashmap string that is adding to the list..that list is passing in this class from which i am extracting the instruction through hashmap again and adding them to listview with the help of list..now problem is listview showing me the data repeating same as the size of the list.

Comment: map1.values().toArray is a "dead copy", not a "live copy", and adding values to the map later will not change its content. In general, please explain more that are you attempting to achieve ant what happens instead.

Comment: @  Audrius Meškauskas i didn't get you

Comment: @ Audrius Meškauskas i explain my question above..please see to it